# Authentication with key Requests

Tags: python, python-requests

```
http://keyXXXXkey@domain.cpm/api/&id_shop=1
```

I have this API that I need to fetch some info from. But I need to use this unique key `keyXXXXkey`
Only with this key, I'm getting authenticated.

How can I do it with the requests library?

if I do it like this

```
response = requests.get("http://keyXXXXkey@domain.cpm/api/&id_shop=1")
```

I'm getting '401 Unauthorized'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your URL accordingly before requesting it. You can do so using [format](https://pyformat.info/):

```
key = 'exampleKey'
response = requests.get("http://{}@domain.cpm/api/&id_shop=1".format(key))
```

Comment: unfortunately, I have same result

Comment: Did you use the real key in your variable ? Obviously if you use keyXXXXkey or exampleKey you won't be able to request the protected URL

Comment: Of course, I'm using a real key, the thing is that I can connect to this web service from my browser using this url

Comment: Are you sure that the key is the only way that your identity is confirmed and that the website is not using cookies or sessions to keep you logged in ? If you go to an incognito window with your browser and just type the correct URL, can you access it ?

Comment: I can do it with incognito but before that, there is Pop Up with username and password, then I enter this key to username field click ok, and then I got authenticated

Comment: Then it gets more complicated. I'd suggest opening at the network tab of your console then look for the request to the right URL and try to look into it. There must be some data stored in a cookie or in a session involved. You need to add these in the header of your request in your python script

Answer (score 0):

If there is session based auth mechanism on this web application, try to use session object:

```
key = 'your_key'
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get('https://{}@domain.com'.format(key), params={"id_shop": 1})
```

Comment: got this response. The requested URL /domain/ was not found on this server.</p>